# How to know which files have been deleted by the antivirus

Tags: antivirus

***I am using Symantec Enterprise 11.0 antivirus***,

> In my environment some important files are missing i wan't know i they
>   are deleted, i have some doubt on my antivirus.

**Is it possible to know which files have been deleted by antivirus, any logs for it**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An antivirus generally keeps the infected files in Quarantine folder or sometimes called Virus Chest. 
You may go through the logs of your antivirus application which will give you a detailed explanation whether your file has been deleted or quarantined or repaired. Good Luck